# How to loop over a list in Java in a minimum step

Tags: java, list, grouping

I have the following for loop, where the StringList is

```
List<String> stringList= new ArrayList<String>();

for (String elementList : stringList) 
   {
        if (elementList =="string1")
        {
            Key=1;
        }
        else if (elementList =="string2")
        {
            Key=0;
        }
   // do some code here 
   }
```

If the (stringList) includes 20,000 string words. The repeating of the words "string1" and "string2" is 10,000 for each in (stringList). it takes time to check every word in the for loop.

How can we make the for loop iterate only two times because there are only two types of words which are "string1" and "string2" regardless of it's repeating in the (stringList)

Comment: note that you should use equals for comparing strings

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: what are you using `Key` for? BTW, I guess you're looking for `break;` there.

Comment: As in you want to stop as soon as you have seen each value 1 time?

Comment: user3127896...ok... thank you for your note

Comment: This is too vague. Do you want to do "some code" for each element or not? What are you doing with `Key`? Can you elaborate on your *real* use case?

Comment: Using a HashSet and its contains method would be significantly more efficient.

Comment: Brett Okken... yes you are correct i need to stop as soon as i found each value one time

Comment: RealSkeptic... the (Key) is an integer and I want to assign it one time as soon as I found each string 1 time

Answer (score 0):

As i said you should use method `equals` for comparing two strings. And also i think you can use method `contains()` to check if your list contains some strings

> contains(Object o) Returns true if this list contains the specified
>   element.

```
if (stringList.contains("string1"))
    Key = 1;
if (stringList.contains("string2"))
    key = 2;
```

Comment: user3127896... if the stringList include 100 types of string value... please help